# How can I make is so that the tail length increases when the snake eats the apple?

Tags: javascript, html

```
tail = 5;
```

**This is the tail start length.**

```
if(ax==px && ay==py) {
    tail++;
    ax=Math.floor(Math.random()*tc);
    ay=Math.floor(Math.random()*tc);
}
```

**Tail++ is what I am trying to change but I cant get it to just add a specific amount to the tail length.**

Comment: `tail += mySpecificAmount;`?

Comment: @PeterMader thanks

Answer (score 1):

`tail++;` increases the value of `tail` by one. It is the same as `tail = tail + 1;`.

If you want to change it by another value (`5`, for example), do this: `tail += 5;`. It is the same as `tail = tail + 5;`.